# Gradient Descent Method with Backtracking Function in R

Tags: r, function, iteration, gradient-descent

I am trying to write a function in R to implement the gradient method with backtracking for a quadratic minimization problem `min{x^T*A*x: x in R5}` and A being a Hilbert matrix. The output of the function should be the number of iterations and the solution to x.
Photo of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vasSN.jpg)

```
A <- hilbert.matrix(5)

dec_gradient <- function(f, g, x_0, s, alpha, beta, epsilon) {
x <- x_0
grad <- g(x)
fun_val <- f(x) 
iter <- 0

while(norm(grad) > epsilon) {
  iter <- iter + 1 
  t <- s
while (fun_val-f(x-t*grad)<alpha*t*norm(grad)^2) {
  t <- beta*t
  x <- x-t*grad
  fun_val <- f(x)
  grad <- g(x)
  print('iter_number = '+ str(iter) + ' norm_grad = ' + str(norm(grad)) + ' fun_val = ' + str(fun_val))
}
  return(x, fun_val)
}
}

f<- t(x)%*%A%*%x
g <- 2*A%*%x
alpha <- 0.5
beta <- 0.5
s <- 1
epsilon <- 10e-4
# define starting point
x_0 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5), ncol = 1)

dec_gradient(f, g, x_0, s, alpha, beta, epsilon)
```

I keep getting the error

> Error in g(x) : could not find function "g"

Comment: When does the error show up? Is after running the last line of code in the code snippet you provided?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I can run my function, but I'm still getting error: Error in norm(grad) : 'A' must be a numeric matrix
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: From a quick glance; your function return value should be `return(list( ... ))` , it looks like inputs `f` and `g` should be functions but they are not.hence the error in your final line. Perhaps you want to define `f` like `f <- function(x, A=A) t(x) %*% A %*% x` and siilarily for `g`.

Comment: @user20650 I changed it to: `f <- function(x, A=A) t(x) %*% A %*% x`
`g <- function(x, A=A) 2* A %*% x` and now I'm getting the error: `Error in g(x) : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?` Should by g be a different function?

Comment: Work through it by breaking it into steps. Get the code running before you put it in a function. Run a block at a time till you see where the error is coming from. (ps should `fun_val <- (x)` be `fun_val <- f(x)` ? -- I dont know the alg but just from the name)

Comment: @user20650, yes, I caught that and fixed it to `fun_val <- f(x)` . It seems like when I run `dec_gradient(f, g, x_0, s, alpha, beta, epsilon)` is when I'm getting the error `Error in g(x) :    promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`

Comment: yep, sorry that is my fault, its due to the `A=A` so define them like `f <- function(x, .A=A) t(x) %*% .A %*% x ; g <- function(x, .A=A) 2* .A %*% x`. This line `print('iter_number = '+ str(iter) + ' norm_grad = ' + str(norm(grad)) + ' fun_val = ' + str(fun_val))` will throw an error. `paste` the values together and `print` e.g. `print(paste( ... ))`

Comment: With all those changes, now when I run `dec_gradient(f, g, x_0, s, alpha, beta, epsilon)`
 This is the error I'm getting: `num 1
Error in "iter_number = " + str(iter) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
Called from: paste("iter_number = " + str(iter) + " norm_grad = " + str(norm(grad)) + 
    " fun_val = " + str(fun_val))
Browse[1]>`

Comment: @HilaryH; yes. My last comment above mentioned that. The line starting `print('iter_number = '+ str(iter)` is not valid R syntax, You do not concatenate strings that way. You normally joinn together using `paste` e.g. `paste("A", 1)`, I am also guessing that you are using `str` to coerce to string??  -- this is not needed (also note that `str` is an R function see `?str`)

Comment: @user20650 is there a better way to print the iteration number along with the norm_grad and fun_val? Obviously `print(paste('iter_number = '+ str(iter) + ' norm_grad = ' + str(norm(grad)) + ' fun_val = ' + str(fun_val)))` won't print the values. Should I break up each value and paste them together?

Comment: `cat(paste0('iter_number = ', iter, "\n",  'norm_grad = ', norm(grad), "\n", 'fun_val = ', fun_val, "\n"))` (note that within `paste` you join values together with a comma and not a `+`)

Comment: @user20650 thank you so much! That really helped! It seems now my function is running, but there is a problem with the values not updating for each iteration. The output is `iter_number = 1
norm_grad = 2.63316458453854
fun_val = 2.39331336763351` over and over and over.

Comment: I had noticed that (but had been to lazy to work through your algo ;)). When debugging things I tend to add print statement like you did. for example, I'd also add a `print(norm(grad))` and `print(iter)` in the outer `while` loop. However, I think that you are missing a parenthesis in the second `while` argument -- should it be `(fun_val - f(x - t*grad)) < alpha*t*norm(grad)^2`? .....

Comment: cont ... However this doesn't solve things. I then added two more print 
statements at the end of the second `while`, adding `print((fun_val - f(x - t*grad)))` and 
`print(alpha*t*norm(grad)^2)` which shows that the values are getting updated.
So if the results are not what you expect then it seems like an implementation 
problem rather than a programming error.

Comment: gah its a misplaced closing curly bracket. You return after the inner while loop rather than the outer

Comment: `dec_gradient <- function(f, g, x_0, s, alpha, beta, epsilon) {
x <- x_0
grad <- g(x)
fun_val <- f(x) 
iter <- 0
while(norm(grad) > epsilon) {
  iter <- iter + 1 
  t <- s
while ((fun_val-f(x-t*grad))<alpha*t*norm(grad)^2) {
  t <- beta*t
  x <- x-t*grad
  fun_val <- f(x)
  grad <- g(x)
  cat(paste0('iter_number = ', iter, "\n",  'norm_grad = ', norm(grad), "\n", 'fun_val = ', fun_val, "\n"))
}
  print(norm(grad))
  print(iter)
  print((fun_val - f(x - t*grad)))
  print(alpha*t*norm(grad)^2)
  return(list(x, fun_val))
}
}` is this what you're referring to wrt to print?

Comment: You are still putting the return statement in the wrong position. Omitting the final four print debugging statements you function should end `} }  return(list(x, fun_val)) }` where the first curly bracket is the inner while, the next the outer while, then the return and then the function end bracket.

Comment: @user20650 ah, it worked(ish)! It's repeating the iteration number. Looking at the 987 lines of output, it's only using iterations 206-214. The norm values and fun_vals are changing, but the iteration number isn't updating according. When I initially run the code, I can see the iteration number start at 1 and go up. this is an example: `iter_number = 214
norm_grad = 0.00099431733532955
fun_val = 0.000110202479873622
iter_number = 214
norm_grad = 0.00099431733532919
fun_val = 0.000110202479873621`

Comment: are you also seeing something like `<console output truncated>` as the output is too long so you are only seeing the last entries. You are also seeing the iterations repeating as you print them in the inner while but only update the counter in the outer while. So move the `cat(paste0('iter_number = ', iter, "\n", ` stuff outside the end of the inner while closing bracket

Comment: @user20650, I'm not getting any messages of `<console output truncated>`. If I want to avoid iterations repeating, should I move `cat(paste0('iter_number = ', iter, "\n",  'norm_grad = ', norm(grad), "\n", 'fun_val = ', fun_val, "\n"))` into the outer while?

Comment: yes end the function `}  cat(paste0('iter_number... }  return(list(x, fun_val)) }`

Comment: @user20650 It worked!! Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to (with help) write the function that worked:

````
dec_gradient <- function(f, g, x_0, s, alpha, beta, epsilon) {
x <- x_0
grad <- g(x)
fun_val <- f(x) 
iter <- 0

while(norm(grad) > epsilon) {
  iter <- iter + 1 
  t <- s
while ((fun_val-f(x-t*grad))<alpha*t*norm(grad)^2) {
  t <- beta*t
  x <- x-t*grad
  fun_val <- f(x)
  grad <- g(x)
} 
  cat(paste0('iter_number = ', iter, "\n",  'norm_grad = ', norm(grad), "\n", 'fun_val = ', fun_val, "\n"))
  }
print(iter)
return(list(x, fun_val)) }


f <- function(x, .A=A) t(x) %*% .A %*% x
g <- function(x, .A=A) 2* .A %*% x
alpha <- 0.5
beta <- 0.5
s <- 1
epsilon <- 10e-4
# define starting point
x_0 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5), ncol = 1)

dec_gradient(f, g, x_0, s, alpha, beta, epsilon) ```
````